# using DMA / i2c on STM32L412

Tags: embedded, stm32, i2c

I want to use an external four-channel I2C DAC. I want this to run continuously, starting a fresh transfer as soon as the old one is finished. Im trying to follow the implementation of the HAL command HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA - this works in my code but only produces a single conversion.

How can i set I2C / DMA to work continuously? Do i have to use a timer to schedule conversions?

Comment: This command will only start one I2C transfer with definable number of data bytes to be received via DMA. I will not send the data continiously. I don't think there is a HAL function for your use-case. Try using the transmit complete interrupt to start the next one.

Comment: that means i have to USE the CPU and interrupts to start the transfer again, right? I was hoping I could run the i2c in the background without using any CPU